# pull value between parenthesis into new column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

There are a few questions & answers on both halves of this question, having issues pulling these together. Take the below snippet, how would one go about creating a new column pulling just the value between the brackets?

```
 Household Income
 'Over $200,000 ($250,000)
 $160,000-$199,000 ($180,000)
 NaN
```

I have a feeling it's using something along this line:

```
s[s.find("(")+1:s.find(")")]
```

I'm just not sure on how to apply it to:

```
df['Income'] = df['Household Income'].*some magic*
```

EDIT:

Solution would be

```
Income
250000
180000
NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['Household Income'] = df['Household Income'].str.replace(',','').str.extract(r"\(\$(.*)\)")
print (df)
  Household Income
0           250000
1           180000
2              NaN
```

And last if need convert to numeric:

```
df['Household Income'] = (df['Household Income'].str.replace(',','')
                                                .str.extract(r"\(\$(.*)\)")
                                                .astype(float)) 
print (df)
   Household Income
0          250000.0
1          180000.0
2               NaN
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked a charm,